# angularjs ui-router onContentLoaded for subviews

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I detect in a view's controller if all the subviews and directives have been fully rendered? Is there an event I could catch or a promise I could wait for to resolve?

I know about the trick with $timeout, but to be honest it makes me feel very uncomfortable.

Comment: Providing a reproducible example, via jsFiddle for example, would be of the utmost use here. Without it we won't be able to build a real solution. You may consider even using Plunkr.

Comment: you can use state resolve service..that could help you..